# NoSuchPortException problem for serial port

Tags: java, serial-port, javax.comm

I tried to connect to SerialPort COM6 using (Windows XP)  **javax.comm** library with this piece of code

```
portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(commName);
        port = portId.open("", Integer.parseInt(timeout));
        serialPort = (SerialPort) port;
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(Integer.parseInt(baudRate), SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
```

but I got exception **NoSuchPortException** and error

```
Error loading SolarisSerial: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no SolarisSerialParallel in java.library.path
Caught java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.comm.SolarisDriver.readRegistrySerial(Ljava/util/Vector;Ljava/lang/String;)I while loading driver com.sun.comm.SolarisDriver
Error loading SolarisSerial: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no SolarisSerialParallel in java.library.path
```

What is wrong with this ? Can anybody please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of this API is [not available on all platforms](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use rxtx libraries for windows.

http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ